# Does loop unrolling on a JIT platfrom (.NET or JVM) provide any benefit

Tags: optimization, loops, jit

I know in C, you can use loop unrolling (unwinding) to help reduce branching in your code but at the expense of program size. That seems to work when you compile to a target machine, however, does it work when you are targeting a platform that performs JIT compilation? Would the JIT negate the need for loop unrolling (possibly even getting in the way)?

Comment: Profile it and see. Turn on the JIT debugging if the system supports that. Each JIT is different (and even within Java you've got Hotspot and JRockit).  Trying to generalize doesn't work well.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html *"Loop unrolling: the Server VM features loop unrolling, ..."*

Comment: @MichaelT I've thought about profiling it but was wondering if there was a general consensus. I will go ahead and try profiling it for .NET. Thanks

Comment: If you dig into Java via HotSpot, there's the flags discussed in [this post](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html).  Glancing at the options, I would say for Java, loop unrolling would have a *detrimental* effect on JIT because it could take it over the -XX:CompileThreshold (which incidentally, has different values for client and server settings), though that would mean doing some profiling.  See also [this blog post](http://blog.headius.com/2009/01/my-favorite-hotspot-jvm-flags.html).

Comment: @Jetti: the general consensus is that you have to profile things like this. The outcome will probably depend on the language, on the Jit, on the programming language, on the version of the Jit, on the particular code, on the optimization level, and on the hardware on which the program runs.